# Is there a non-baking method of merging actions together

Tags: animation, keyframes, nla-editor

While it's possible to bake animation data, it usually outputs many keyframes to preserve the overall animation. Lots of keyframes are very tedious to edit. Is there a way of merging strips into a 'normal' Action (not a meta-strip) that doesn't involve baking? This would allow tangent (editing) handles of any animation channel (assuming there's nothing else stacked on them) to be saved into (the) new strip and would make it a lot easier to edit animation. Are there any current methods aimed at doing this?

If not, would anyone else be interested in this kind of feature?  Please comment (not answer) if that would be a feature you would use.